# Application has encountered a problem and needs to close

Tags: c#-3.0

I need to find where the application is running into an unhandled exception. I am supporting this from a previous developer. The application is running and the users aren't interacting with it at the time it crashes. I have ran it in debug mode and it doesn't crash. I know the project in the solution where it happens, but that code is like almost 10,000 lines. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Add subscription to the AppDomain.UnhandledException event as early as you can:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += YourHandler
```

Inside you can log the exception information and anlyze it later

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving much to go on. You might want to look up [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isnt much info given in the post above. I found following article alot more better:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions